# Error when installing ggthemes r-package developer version from github

Tags: r, ggplot2

I encounter an error when installing [Jeffrey Arnold](http://www.jrnold.me/) package from [github](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes).

```
library("devtools")
install_github("ggthemes", "jrnold")
Installing github repo(s) ggthemes/master from jrnold
Installing ggthemes.zip from https://api.github.com/repos/jrnold/ggthemes/zipball/master
Error as.list(param_pieces[, 2]) : Index out of bounds
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting this error when I'm installing it from github.  Can you open up an issue on github? Include the output of `sessionInfo()`. Also set `options(error=recover)` before running it so I can get a sense of where the error is occurring.

Comment: Thank you. I will send a feedback.